How to calculate daily returns and volatility from intraday price?
Imagine I have 30-minute price data like this:
temp = pd.DataFrame({'price' : np.random.randint(100, 120, 500)}, index = pd.date_range(start = '2024-1-1', freq = '30min', periods = 500))
temp['rets'] = temp.price / temp.price.shift(1)
temp['log_rets'] = np.log(temp['rets'])
temp.dropna(inplace = True)

print(temp)

                    price   rets    log_rets
2024-01-01 00:30:00 111 1.11000 0.10436
2024-01-01 01:00:00 103 0.92793 -0.07480
2024-01-01 01:30:00 100 0.97087 -0.02956
2024-01-01 02:00:00 113 1.13000 0.12222
2024-01-01 02:30:00 108 0.95575 -0.04526
... ... ... ...
2024-01-11 07:30:00 102 0.89474 -0.11123
2024-01-11 08:00:00 106 1.03922 0.03847
2024-01-11 08:30:00 108 1.01887 0.01869
2024-01-11 09:00:00 117 1.08333 0.08004
2024-01-11 09:30:00 116 0.99145 -0.00858
499 rows × 3 columns

Are my calculations of average daily and annualized returns and volatility below correct (in percentage, not log)? If yes, do I need to multiply them by 100 to get %?
daily_log_rets = temp['log_rets'].resample('B').sum()

# daily:
daily_mean_rets_percentage = (np.exp(daily_log_rets.mean()) - 1)
daily_rets_volatility = (np.exp(daily_log_rets.std()) - 1) 

#annualized:
annualized_mean_rets_percentage = np.exp(daily_log_rets.mean() * 252) - 1
annualized_rets_volatility = (np.exp(daily_log_rets) - 1).std() * 252 ** .5


You only shift by 30 min. So your return is per 30 min.

Thank you. I understand that. But my question is if I scaled the returns and standard deviations to daily and annualized correctly or not. Please see the last 5 lines of the code.

If zou use the standard close-to-close HV calculation you use daily data. That's why you multiply by sqrt(260) to annualize (or something close to 260, depending on trading days and your preference).
On Bloomberg HVT, looking at AMC US Equity, you see that HV for 10 days was 28.964 for AMC US Equity on 21.7.2023.

In Python:
dates = ['21.07.2023', '20.07.2023', '19.07.2023', '18.07.2023', '17.07.2023', '14.07.2023', '13.07.2023', '12.07.2023', '11.07.2023', '10.07.2023', '07.07.2023', '06.06.2023']
vals = [4.4, 4.33, 4.37, 4.31, 4.37, 4.33, 4.44, 4.4, 4.39, 4.24, 4.2, 4.29]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Dates":dates, "Price" : vals})
round(np.std([np.log(df.Price[i]/df.Price[i+1]) for i in range(0,9)], ddof = 1)*np.sqrt(260)*100,3)

which yields exactly what BBG shows.

If you have 30 min intervals, you do not have daily returns but 30 min returns. Each day has 48 returns (provided you have a complete 24h trading day like in FX). Hence, you multiply by $sqrt(260*48)$. If you have Bloomberg, look at VOLC and Hist Vol. HF for High frequency, which is really just the 30 min BFIX intervals. If you try to replicate it, you will see it also uses $sqrt(260*48)$.

In some days, the trading day may end sooner so not all my days have the same number of measurements. Will the formula that are based on daily returns work correctly if I summate the 30-minute log returns by day and then use those daily log returns in the formula?

btw, you should divide Price[i+1] by Price[i] and not vice versa. Even better, instead of the list comprehension, try this: log_rets = np.log(df.Price / df.Price.shift(1))
